# Best way to compute $A^{-1}$ when the Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^T$ is known

Tags: inverse, computational-complexity, cholesky-decomposition

Suppose $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric positive definite, and that I have available the Cholesky decomposition of $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{L}_A\mathbf{L}_A^T$. I want to know $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$. Which of the two methods below are best (fastest, robust, or any other quality indicators)?

1. Compute $\mathbf{L}_A^{-1}$ and then $\mathbf{A}^{-1}=\mathbf{L}_A^{-T}\mathbf{L}_A^{-1}$. *EDIT: Here, I re-use $\mathbf{L}_A$ from a previous step in my calculations, so assume no computational cost of obtaining $\mathbf{L}_A$.*
2. Compute $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ directly. E.g. MATLAB applies first the LU decomposition and then uses the results to form a linear system whose solution is $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html#d123e769694.

Comment: Tangential question, but why would you want to compute $A^{-1}$?

Comment: I have $L_A$ from a previous section in my algorithm, and in the next part I need $A^{-1}$.  Since $L_A$ is lower triangluar, I was wondering if it is possible to exploit this structure when calculating $L_A^{-1}$.

Comment: Why does the next part of your algorithm  need $A^{-1}$ though? A rule of thumb in numerical linear algebra is that one usually should not form $A^{-1}$ explicitly.

Comment: In my case, $A^{-1}$ is used as a weight in a subsequent optimization problem. I have $J=x^T(B+A^{-1})x -2(C+dA^{-1})x$ and I want to minimize $J$ wrt $x$. Here, $B$ and $C$ are given matrices and $d$ is a given vector.

I don't see how I can avoid calculating $A^{-1}$ explicitly in this case, but if you have an idea that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method (1). An efficient method of inverting a lower triangular matrix ($L$, in this case) requires $ < n^3/2 + n^2/2 $ operations.<sup>[1]</sup>
Computing the product $L^{-T}L^{-1}$ requires $2n^3/3+n/3$ operations using an efficient method for multiplying triangular matrices.<sup>[2]</sup>

Method (2). Since you already have Cholesky factors, you should not perform LU decomposition in order to compute $A^{-1}$; because doing so, would effectively mean that you are deriving Cholesky factors again! This only incurs unnecessary cost. In this case, you can solve two triangular systems (each would cost $n^3/2 +n^2/2$ arithmetic operations) using the well-known method:

$$\text{Data: } L, L^T. \text{ Output: }X=A^{-1}$$
\begin{align*}
AX &= I \\
L(L^TX) &= I
\end{align*}
\begin{equation}
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    i)\ LY=I & \rightarrow Y\ ✔ \\
    ii)\ L^{T}X = Y & \rightarrow X=A^{-1}\ ✔ 
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

Summing the operations count, you'll find that the second method requires less computation if properly implemented. If you are using MATLAB built-in functions, I believe the following command would be fastest way to compute $A^{-1}$:

```
X = L' \ (L \ eye(n));
```

As a final note, I would like to give a quote from Meyer<sup>[3]</sup> discussing the same problem:

> A tempting alternate solution might be to use the fact $A^{-1} = (LU)^{−1} =
> U^{−1}L^{−1}$. But computing $U^{−1}$ and $L^{−1}$ explicitly and then multiplying the results **is not as computationally efficient as the method just described.**

EDIT:

Below, is a naïve performance comparison of the two methods in MATLAB for randomly generated s.p.d matrices. As you can see, on average, you will get slightly faster results with method (2).
[image]

<sup>[1] <sub>Stewart, Gilbert W. Matrix algorithms: volume 1: basic decompositions. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 1998, chapter 2, section 2, algorithm 2.3.</sub></sup>

<sup>[2] <sub>Lyche, Tom. Numerical linear algebra and matrix factorizations. Vol. 22. Springer Nature, 2020..</sub></sup>

<sup>[3] <sub>Meyer, Carl D. Matrix analysis and applied linear algebra. Vol. 71. Siam, 2000.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

From the book of Nick Higham on "Functions of Matrices Theory and Computation", we can find the theoretical number of flops for both LU and Cholesky factorization where $n$ is the A matrix size $n \times n$.

In general, Cholesky $\mathcal{O}(n^3/3)$ is twice as fast as LU decomposition $\mathcal{O}(2n^3/3)$ but depending on your matrix, LU can be made faster in the order magnitude of $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am interested in $A^{-1}$ and not necessarily it's decompositions. Is it faster to compute $L_A^{-1}$ than directly $A^{-1}$? I was thinking that the lower triangular structure of $L_A$ would make it easier somehow to calulate $L_A^{-1}$ than directly $A^{-1}$.

Comment: You get the inverse $A^{-1}$ by the inverse of your decomposed matrices. Well, the given table shows you the complete computation cost of the decomposed matrices of LU and Cholesky decompositions. If you want to compute $L_A^{-1}$ from $L_A$ to get $A^{-1}$, the computation cost would still be the same at the end since the other method also computes the inverse of its decomposed matrices.

Comment: Yes, but since I already have $L_A$ from a previous step in my calculations then I avoid the cost of doing the decomposition of $A$ again, right? At least in MATLAB, it seems that decomposition would be some kind of LU-decomposition of $A$, and in my specific case that extra decomposition would probably be redundant. So based on what you said, it seems to me that it is cheaper to re-use $L_A$ (assume no cost) to calculate $L_{A}^{-1}$ and then $A^{-1}$ than calculating $A^{-1}$ "directly" (where "directly" means doing first a LU-decomposition and then inverting the decomposed matrices)

Comment: I edited the question slightly to emphasize that there is no cost in re-using $L_A$.

Answer (score 0):

I know this bit old, but for future readers, you said you need $A^{-1}$ in order to compute $J=x^T(B+A^{-1})x -2(C+dA^{-1})x$. What you should be doing is write the parts with inverses as matrix-vector products e.g. $x^T(A^{-1}x)$, where you first compute $A^{-1}x=z$ by solving the system $Az=x$ (in the way @S4JJ4D but with different RHS), which is cheap ($O(n^2)$ to solve as you have the cholesky factors given). Then you finally compute $x^T z$.